# How to find and delete with Active Record

Tags: plugin-development, database

I'm trying to learn how to add and delete records using Active Record.

This works to add:

```
$instance = new Calendar37Record;
$instance->timestr = $timestr;
$success = $instance->save();
```

Given that I know the id of the record to delete, is the process to find the record and then delete it? Or can you just delete it?  I tried this, but it doesn't seem to find the record, and it complains 'The active record cannot be deleted because it is new.':

```
$instance = new Calendar37Record;
$instance->findByPk($id); 
$success = $instance->delete();
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$instance = new Calendar37Record;
$instance->deleteByPk($id);
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. I think I shouldn't stay up so late at night.